# Minors of low rank skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants, matrix-theory

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrix of rank $r$.
Given subsets $X$ and $Y$ of row and column indices respectively, let $A_{X,Y}$ denote the submatrix of $A$ obtained by only keeping rows with indices in $X$ and columns with indices in $Y$.

Prove that for any subsets $X, Y\subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ each of size $r$, we have

$$\det A_{X,X} \cdot \det A_{Y,Y} = (-1)^r (\det A_{X,Y})^2.$$

I've heard that this theorem is due to Frobenius, but have not been able to track down a reference that proves this result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no one else has posted a complete answer so far, let me give one.
Note that it is only complete in the sense of answering the OP's question;
several other questions arise that I cannot easily address.

In Section 1, I will prove the main result (Theorem 1), which is more general
than the OP's equality. In Section 2, I will derive the latter from the
former. In Sections 3 and 4, I will generalize the statement and ask further questions.

## 1. On size-$r$ minors of a rank-$r$ matrix

We fix a field $\mathbb{K}$. (In Section 3, we will generalize this to a
commutative ring.)

Let $\mathbb{N}=\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
let $\left[  n\right]  $ denote the set $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $.

If $A=\left(  a_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq m}\in
\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ is an $n\times m$-matrix (for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}
$), and if $I\subseteq\left[  n\right]  $ and $J\subseteq\left[  m\right]  $
are arbitrary subsets, then $A_{I,J}$ will denote the submatrix $\left(
a_{i_{x},j_{y}}\right)  _{1\leq x\leq p,\ 1\leq y\leq q}$ of $A$, where the
subsets $I$ and $J$ have been written as $I=\left\{  i_{1}<i_{2}<\cdots
<i_{p}\right\}  $ and $J=\left\{  j_{1}<j_{2}<\cdots<j_{q}\right\}  $. (Thus,
$A_{I,J}$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ upon removing all rows other than
the rows indexed by elements of $I$ and removing all columns other than the
columns indexed by elements of $J$.)

The crucial result is the following:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n,m,r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ be a
> matrix such that $\operatorname*{rank}A\leq r$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of
> $\left[  n\right]  $, and let $U$ and $V$ be subsets of $\left[  m\right]  $;
> assume that $\left\vert X\right\vert =\left\vert Y\right\vert =\left\vert
> U\right\vert =\left\vert V\right\vert =r$. Then,
> \begin{align*}
> \det\left(  A_{X,U}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,V}\right)  =\det\left(
> A_{X,V}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,U}\right)  .
> \end{align*}

Theorem 1 is surprisingly easy to prove using the following two basic facts:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $n,m,r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ be a
> matrix such that $\operatorname*{rank}A\leq r$. Then, there exist two matrices
> $B\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times r}$ and $C\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times m}$ such that $A=BC$.

*Proof of Lemma 2.* The particular case of Lemma 2 when $\operatorname*{rank}
A=r$ is a well-known result in elementary linear algebra, but since the
general case is rarely stated, let me sketch the proof (for the general case):

Let $\operatorname*{Col}A$ denote the span of the columns of $A$. This is a
$\mathbb{K}$-vector subspace of $\mathbb{K}^{n\times1}$. Its dimension is
$\dim\left(  \operatorname*{Col}A\right)  =\operatorname*{rank}A\leq r$. In
other words, the $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $\operatorname*{Col}A$ has
dimension $\leq r$. Thus, this $\mathbb{K}$-vector space has a basis with at
most $r$ elements. Therefore, this vector space can be generated by exactly
$r$ elements (just take a basis with at most $r$ elements, and insert the zero
vector enough times to get exactly $r$ generators). In other words, there
exist $r$ vectors $v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{r}$ that span the vector space
$\operatorname*{Col}A$. Consider these $v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{r}$.

Now, let $B\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times r}$ be the matrix whose $r$ columns are
$v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{r}$. For each $i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,m\right\}  $, we
have
\begin{align*}
\left(  \text{the }i\text{-th column of }A\right)   &  \in\operatorname*{Col}
A\qquad\left(  \text{by the definition of }\operatorname*{Col}A\right) \\
&  =\operatorname*{span}\left(  v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{r}\right)
\end{align*}
(since $v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{r}$ span $\operatorname*{Col}A$); thus, there
exist scalars $c_{i,1},c_{i,2},\ldots,c_{i,r}\in\mathbb{K}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\left(  \text{the }i\text{-th column of }A\right)  =c_{i,1}v_{1}+c_{i,2}
v_{2}+\cdots+c_{i,r}v_{r}.
\end{align*}
Consider these scalars $c_{i,1},c_{i,2},\ldots,c_{i,r}$. Define the matrix
$C\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times m}$ by $C=\left(  c_{j,i}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
r,\ 1\leq j\leq m}$. Then, it is easy to see that $A=BC$. This proves Lemma 2.
$\blacksquare$

> **Lemma 3.** Let $n,m,r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $B\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times r}$ and
> $C\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times m}$ be two matrices. Let $X\subseteq\left[  n\right]
> $ and $U\subseteq\left[  m\right]  $ be two subsets. Then,
> \begin{align*}
> \left(  BC\right)  _{X,U}=B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }C_{\left[  r\right]  ,U}.
> \end{align*}

*Proof of Lemma 3.* Straightforward entry-by-entry verification (using the
definition of matrix multiplication). $\blacksquare$

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Lemma 2 yields that there exist two matrices
$B\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times r}$ and $C\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times m}$ such that
$A=BC$. Consider these $B$ and $C$. Now, Lemma 3 yields $\left(  BC\right)
_{X,U}=B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }C_{\left[  r\right]  ,U}$. In view of $A=BC$,
this rewrites as $A_{X,U}=B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }C_{\left[  r\right]  ,U}$.
But the matrix is $B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }$ is square (since $\left\vert
X\right\vert =r=\left\vert \left[  r\right]  \right\vert $), and so is the
matrix $C_{\left[  r\right]  ,U}$ (since $\left\vert U\right\vert
=r=\left\vert \left[  r\right]  \right\vert $); hence, $\det\left(
B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }C_{\left[  r\right]  ,U}\right)  =\det\left(
B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }\right)  \cdot\det\left(  C_{\left[  r\right]
,U}\right)  $. In view of $A_{X,U}=B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }C_{\left[
r\right]  ,U}$, this rewrites as
\begin{equation}
\det\left(  A_{X,U}\right)  =\det\left(  B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }\right)
\cdot\det\left(  C_{\left[  r\right]  ,U}\right)  .
\label{eq.darij1.pf.t1.AXU}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Similar reasoning shows that
\begin{align}
\det\left(  A_{X,V}\right)   &  =\det\left(  B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }\right)
\cdot\det\left(  C_{\left[  r\right]  ,V}\right)  ;
\label{eq.darij1.pf.t1.AXV}
\tag{2}
\\
\det\left(  A_{Y,U}\right)   &  =\det\left(  B_{Y,\left[  r\right]  }\right)
\cdot\det\left(  C_{\left[  r\right]  ,U}\right)  ;
\label{eq.darij1.pf.t1.AYU}
\tag{3}
\\
\det\left(  A_{Y,V}\right)   &  =\det\left(  B_{Y,\left[  r\right]  }\right)
\cdot\det\left(  C_{\left[  r\right]  ,V}\right)  .
\label{eq.darij1.pf.t1.AYV}
\tag{4}
\end{align}

Multiplying the equalities \eqref{eq.darij1.pf.t1.AXU} and
\eqref{eq.darij1.pf.t1.AYV}, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\det\left(  A_{X,U}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,V}\right)   &  =\det\left(
B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }\right)  \cdot\det\left(  C_{\left[  r\right]
,U}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  B_{Y,\left[  r\right]  }\right)  \cdot\det\left(
C_{\left[  r\right]  ,V}\right) \\
&  =\underbrace{\det\left(  B_{X,\left[  r\right]  }\right)  \cdot\det\left(
C_{\left[  r\right]  ,V}\right)  }_{\substack{=\det\left(  A_{X,V}\right)
\\\text{(by \eqref{eq.darij1.pf.t1.AXV})}}}\cdot\underbrace{\det\left(
B_{Y,\left[  r\right]  }\right)  \cdot\det\left(  C_{\left[  r\right]
,U}\right)  }_{\substack{=\det\left(  A_{Y,U}\right)  \\\text{(by
\eqref{eq.darij1.pf.t1.AYU})}}}\\
&  =\det\left(  A_{X,V}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,U}\right)  .
\end{align*}
This proves Theorem 1. $\blacksquare$

## 2. The skew-symmetric case

Recall that a square matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ is said to be
*skew-symmetric* if it satisfies $A^{T}=-A$. Now you claim:

> **Theorem 4.** Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ be a skew-symmetric matrix.
> Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $\operatorname*{rank}A\leq r$. Let $X$ and
> $Y$ be subsets of $\left[  n\right]  $ such that $\left\vert X\right\vert
> =\left\vert Y\right\vert =r$. Then,
> \begin{align*}
> \det\left(  A_{X,X}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,Y}\right)  =\left(
> -1\right)  ^{r}\cdot\left(  \det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  \right)  ^{2}.
> \end{align*}

*Proof of Theorem 4.* The matrix $A$ is skew-symmetric; thus, $A^{T}=-A$.
Now,
\begin{align*}
\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  ^{T}  &  =\left(  A^{T}\right)  _{Y,X}=\left(
-A\right)  _{Y,X}\qquad\left(  \text{since }A^{T}=-A\right) \\
&  =-A_{Y,X}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\det\left(  \left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  ^{T}\right)  =\det\left(
-A_{Y,X}\right)  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{r}\det\left(  A_{Y,X}\right)  $ (since
$A_{Y,X}$ is an $r\times r$-matrix). But the determinant of a matrix does not
change when the matrix is transposed. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  =\det\left(  \left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  ^{T}\right)
=\left(  -1\right)  ^{r}\det\left(  A_{Y,X}\right)  .
\end{align*}

Now, Theorem 1 (applied to $U=X$ and $V=Y$) yields
\begin{align*}
\det\left(  A_{X,X}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,Y}\right)  =\det\left(
A_{X,Y}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,X}\right)  .
\end{align*}
Comparing this with
\begin{align*}
&  \left(  -1\right)  ^{r}\cdot\left(  \det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  \right)
^{2}\\
&  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{r}\cdot\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  \cdot
\underbrace{\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  }_{=\left(  -1\right)  ^{r}\det\left(
A_{Y,X}\right)  }\\
&  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{r}\cdot\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  \cdot\left(
-1\right)  ^{r}\det\left(  A_{Y,X}\right) \\
&  =\underbrace{\left(  -1\right)  ^{r}\cdot\left(  -1\right)  ^{r}}_{=\left(
-1\right)  ^{2r}=1}\cdot\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  \cdot\det\left(
A_{Y,X}\right)  =\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,X}\right)
,
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\det\left(  A_{X,X}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,Y}\right)  =\left(
-1\right)  ^{r}\cdot\left(  \det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  \right)  ^{2}.
\end{align*}
This proves Theorem 4. $\blacksquare$

Note that if $\mathbb{K}$ is a field of characteristic $\neq2$, then the rank
of any skew-symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ is even. This is a
known fact, implicit in [Keith Conrad, *Bilinear
Forms*](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf)
(combine Theorem 1.6 and formula (5.3) in this document).

## 3. Generalizing to commutative rings

Now, let us generalize our situation. Instead of requiring $\mathbb{K}$ to be
a field, we now merely assume that $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring. Does
Theorem 1 still hold? The answer will depend on how we define
$\operatorname*{rank}A$. There is no "obviously right" definition of "rank" of
a matrix over a commutative ring, but there are several contenders. We look
specifically for a notion that generalizes the statement
"$\operatorname*{rank}A\leq r$". Two candidates are the following:

> We say that a matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ has *strong rank $\leq r$*
> (for some $r\in\mathbb{N}$) if there exist two matrices $B\in\mathbb{K}
> ^{n\times r}$ and $C\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times m}$ such that $A=BC$.

> We say that a matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ has *weak rank $\leq r$*
> (for some $r\in\mathbb{N}$) if every two $\left(  r+1\right)  $-element
> subsets $X\subseteq\left[  n\right]  $ and $Y\subseteq\left[  m\right]  $
> satisfy $\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  =0$.

It is easy to see (using the Cauchy--Binet theorem) that every matrix that has
strong rank $\leq r$ must also have weak rank $\leq r$. The converse is not
true (in fact, for $n=2$ and $r=1$, it boils down to [the pre-pre-Schreier condition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14555/first-order-ufd-factorial-ring-condition-pre-schreier-rings)).

Our above proof of Theorem 1 obviously proves the following generalization:

> **Theorem 5.** Let $n,m,r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ be a
> matrix that has strong rank $\leq r$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of $\left[
> n\right]  $, and let $U$ and $V$ be subsets of $\left[  m\right]  $; assume
> that $\left\vert X\right\vert =\left\vert Y\right\vert =\left\vert
> U\right\vert =\left\vert V\right\vert =r$. Then,
> \begin{align*}
> \det\left(  A_{X,U}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,V}\right)  =\det\left(
> A_{X,V}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,U}\right)  .
> \end{align*}

But we also have the following more general fact:

> **Theorem 6.** Let $n,m,r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ be a
> matrix that has weak rank $\leq r$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of $\left[
> n\right]  $, and let $U$ and $V$ be subsets of $\left[  m\right]  $; assume
> that $\left\vert X\right\vert =\left\vert Y\right\vert =\left\vert
> U\right\vert =\left\vert V\right\vert =r$. Then,
> \begin{align*}
> \det\left(  A_{X,U}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,V}\right)  =\det\left(
> A_{X,V}\right)  \cdot\det\left(  A_{Y,U}\right)  .
> \end{align*}

The only way I can currently prove Theorem 6 is by reducing it to Theorem 5
using the "meta-theorem" saying that every polynomial identity in the entries
of a matrix that holds (universally, i.e., over every $\mathbb{K}$) for all
matrices having strong rank $\leq r$ must also hold for all matrices having
weak rank $\leq r$. This "meta-theorem" follows from some standard monomial
theory, specifically the result that the quotient of the coordinate ring of
$\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ modulo the ideal generated by all $\left(
r+1\right)  \times\left(  r+1\right)  $-minors can be embedded into the
coordinate ring of $\mathbb{K}^{n\times r}\times\mathbb{K}^{r\times m}$ via
the $A=BC$ substitution (with $B\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times r}$ and $C\in
\mathbb{K}^{r\times m}$). The latter fact is proved implicitly in Section 5 of
[Richard G. Swan, *On the straightening law for minors of a matrix*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06696v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06696v1).

> **Question 7.** Is there a "natural" proof of Theorem 6?

## 4. Pfaffians

If we are already looking at skew-symmetric matrices, it isn't a long stretch
to move on to alternating matrices any more.

Recall that a square matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ is said to be
*alternating* if it is skew-symmetric (i.e., satisfies $A^{T}=-A$) and all its
diagonal entries are $0$. If the field $\mathbb{K}$ has characteristic $\neq
2$, then every alternating matrix is skew-symmetric; but this is not true in
characteristic $2$. Any alternating matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ has a
well-defined [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian)
$\operatorname*{Pf}A\in\mathbb{K}$ satisfying $\det A=\left(
\operatorname*{Pf}A\right)  ^{2}$. Note that $\operatorname*{Pf}A=0$ if $n$ is
odd. Properties of Pfaffians come up in the literature all the time; there is
[a MathOverflow question collecting references on
them](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280362/detailed-modern-references-for-basic-properties-of-pfaffians-over-commutative-ri).
(It is probably worth adding the recent preprint [arXiv:2008.04247v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04247v1).)

It is now not too hard to show the following:

> **Theorem 8.** Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. Let $n,r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let
> $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ be an alternating matrix such that
> $\operatorname*{rank}A\leq r$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of $\left[
> n\right]  $ such that $\left\vert X\right\vert =\left\vert Y\right\vert =r$.
> Then,
> \begin{align*}
> \operatorname*{Pf}\left(  A_{X,X}\right)  \cdot\operatorname*{Pf}\left(
> A_{Y,Y}\right)  =\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)  .
> \end{align*}

Indeed, this relies on the following analogue of Lemma 2:

> **Lemma 9.** Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. Let $n,r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let
> $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ be an alternating matrix such that
> $\operatorname*{rank}A\leq r$. Then, there exist a matrix $S\in\mathbb{K}
> ^{r\times n}$ and an alternating matrix $B\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times r}$ such that
> $A=S^{T}BS$.

*Proof of Lemma 9 (rough outline).* We will use the results of the
(expository) paper [Keith Conrad, *Bilinear
Forms*](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf).
We translate the claim into the language of alternating bilinear forms. Set
$V=\mathbb{K}^{n\times1}$, and let $f:V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ be the
alternating bilinear form corresponding to $A$. (Thus, explicitly, it is the
form $\left(  x,y\right)  \mapsto x^{T}Ay$.) Let $R$ be the subspace $\left\{
v\in V\ \mid\ f\left(  v,w\right)  =0\text{ for all }w\in V\right\}
=\operatorname*{Ker}A$ of $V$. (This is often called the *radical* of $f$.)
Then, $f$ descends to an alternating bilinear form $\overline{f}$ on the
quotient space $V/R$. Choose any basis $\left(  w_{1},w_{2},\ldots
,w_{g}\right)  $ for the latter quotient space; then,
\begin{align*}
g=\dim\left(  V/R\right)  =\underbrace{\dim V}_{=n}-\dim\underbrace{R}
_{=\operatorname*{Ker}A}=n-\dim\left(  \operatorname*{Ker}A\right)
=\operatorname*{rank}A\leq r.
\end{align*}
Let $B_{0}\in\mathbb{K}^{g\times g}$ be the alternating matrix that represents
the bilinear form $\overline{f}$ on this basis $\left(  w_{1},w_{2}
,\ldots,w_{g}\right)  $. Let $S_{0}\in\mathbb{K}^{g\times n}$ be the matrix
that represents the projection map $V\rightarrow V/R$ with respect to the
standard basis of $V=\mathbb{K}^{n\times1}$ and the basis $\left(  w_{1}
,w_{2},\ldots,w_{g}\right)  $ of $V/R$. Then, it is easy to see that
$A=S_{0}^{T}B_{0}S_{0}$. By adding $r-g$ zero rows and columns to $B_{0}$ and
$r-g$ zero rows to $S_{0}$, we obtain two matrices $B\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times
r}$ and $S\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times n}$ such that $B$ is alternating and such
that $A=S^{T}BS$. This proves Lemma 9. $\blacksquare$

[*Remark:* Lemma 9 can be made a lot stronger if we assume
$\operatorname*{rank}A=r$. Indeed, in this case, we can say that $r$ is even,
and that $A$ can be written in the form $A=S^{T}JS$, where $S\in
\mathbb{K}^{r\times n}$ is some matrix, and where $J$ is the "standard"
skew-symmetric $r\times r$-matrix (i.e., the block matrix $\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{cc}
0 & I_{r/2}\\
-I_{r/2} & 0
\end{array}
\right)  $). This follows from the fact that the alternating bilinear form
$\overline{f}$ in the above proof of Lemma 9 is non-degenerate and thus has a
symplectic basis. (And this basis has size $g=r$, because
$\operatorname*{rank}A=r$.)]

> **Lemma 10.** Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $B\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times r}$ be an
> alternating matrix. Let $K\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times r}$ be any matrix. Then,
> \begin{align*}
> \operatorname*{Pf}\left(  K^{T}BK\right)  =\det K\cdot\operatorname*{Pf}B.
> \end{align*}

For proofs of Lemma 10, see (e.g.) Teorema 8.6.3 (1) in [Marco Manetti,
*Algebra lineare, per matematici*,
2020-09-13](https://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/manetti/dispense/algebralineare.pdf).
A more general fact -- which relates to Lemma 10 in the same way as the
Cauchy-Binet formula relates to the classical $\det\left(  UV\right)  =\det
U\cdot\det V$ -- is Ishikawa/Wakayama's "Minor Summation Formula" as stated in
[Masao Ishikawa, Masato Wakayama, *Minor Summation Formula of Pfaffians*,
Linear and Multilinear Algebra **39** (1995), pp. 285--305](https://doi.org/10.1080/03081089508818403).

*Proof of Theorem 8 (rough outline).* Lemma 9 yields that there exist a matrix
$S\in\mathbb{K}^{r\times n}$ and an alternating matrix $B\in\mathbb{K}
^{r\times r}$ such that $A=S^{T}BS$. Consider these $S$ and $B$.

From $A=S^{T}BS$, it is easy to see that
\begin{equation}
A_{X,Y}=\underbrace{\left(  S^{T}\right)  _{X,\left[  r\right]  }}_{=\left(
S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  ^{T}}BS_{\left[  r\right]  ,Y}=\left(
S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  ^{T}BS_{\left[  r\right]  ,Y}.
\label{eq.darij1.pf.t8.4}
\tag{5}
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)   &  =\det\left(  \left(  S_{\left[  r\right]
,X}\right)  ^{T}BS_{\left[  r\right]  ,Y}\right)  =\underbrace{\det\left(
\left(  S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  ^{T}\right)  }_{=\det\left(
S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  }\cdot\det B\cdot\det\left(  S_{\left[
r\right]  ,Y}\right) \nonumber\\
&  =\det\left(  S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  \cdot\det B\cdot\det\left(
S_{\left[  r\right]  ,Y}\right)  .
\label{eq.darij1.pf.t8.5}
\tag{6}
\end{align}
Similarly to \eqref{eq.darij1.pf.t8.4}, we also obtain
\begin{align*}
A_{X,X}=\left(  S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  ^{T}BS_{\left[  r\right]
,X},
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname*{Pf}\left(  A_{X,X}\right)  =\operatorname*{Pf}\left(  \left(
S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  ^{T}BS_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)
=\det\left(  S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  \cdot\operatorname*{Pf}B
\end{align*}
(by Lemma 10). Likewise,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname*{Pf}\left(  A_{Y,Y}\right)  =\det\left(  S_{\left[  r\right]
,Y}\right)  \cdot\operatorname*{Pf}B.
\end{align*}
Multiplying the preceding two equalities and recalling that $\left(
\operatorname*{Pf}B\right)  ^{2}=\det B$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\operatorname*{Pf}\left(  A_{X,X}\right)  \cdot\operatorname*{Pf}\left(
A_{Y,Y}\right)  =\det\left(  S_{\left[  r\right]  ,X}\right)  \cdot\det\left(
S_{\left[  r\right]  ,Y}\right)  \cdot\det B=\det\left(  A_{X,Y}\right)
\end{align*}
(by \eqref{eq.darij1.pf.t8.5}). This proves Theorem 8. $\blacksquare$

Note that squaring the equality in Theorem 8 yields the claim of Theorem 4
(albeit only in the case when $A$ is alternating).

> **Question 9.** Can Theorem 8 be generalized to commutative rings $\mathbb{K}$
> ? This is trickier than one might expect, as the notions of "weak rank" and
> "strong rank" probably need to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution: Assume $X$ and $Y$ partition $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Hence $A$ is in the block form 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
B_{r\times r}&C_{r\times r}\\
-^{\rm{T}}C_{r\times r}&D_{r\times r} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $B$ and $D$ are skew-symmetric. One needs to show that if the rank of the matrix above is $r$, then $\det(B)\det(D)=(-1)^r\left(\det(C)\right)^2$. The dimension of the null space must be $r$. A column vector 
$\begin{bmatrix}
v_{r\times 1}\\
w_{r\times 1}
\end{bmatrix}$
is killed by $A$ iff 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
Bv+Cw=\mathbf{0}\\
-^{\rm{T}}Cv+Dw=\mathbf{0}
\end{cases}.
\end{equation*}
If $B$ is invertible, we can solve the first equation for $v$ to obtain  $v=-B^{-1}Cw$. Substituting in the second equation yields $(^{\rm{T}}CB^{-1}C+D)w=0$. Thus the dimension of the null space of $A$ is the same as that of the $r\times r$ matrix $^{\rm{T}}CB^{-1}C+D$. Hence this matrix must be zero. We conclude that $^{\rm{T}}CB^{-1}C=-D$. Taking determinants of both sides we obtain  $\det(^{\rm{T}}CB^{-1}C)=(-1)^r\det(D)$, and hence $\det(B)\det(D)=(-1)^r\left(\det(C)\right)^2$.

If $B$ is singular, it suffices to argue that $C$ is singular as well. Aiming for a contradiction, if $C$ is invertible one may solve the first equation for $v$ to obtain $w=-C^{-1}Bv$. Substituting in the second equation, a similar argument shows $^{\rm{T}}C+DC^{-1}B=\mathbf{O}_{r\times r}$. This is a contradiction since $^{\rm{T}}C$ is invertible while $B$ and hence $DC^{-1}B$ are singular.